# Generate Unique Random Numbers in Blank Cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

My data Range is A1 to A9.

Cell A2, A4, A6, A8 are blank Cell.

A1, A3, A5, A7, A9 has values are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

I want to generate unique Random number in blank cells like 6, 7, 8 & 9.
I'm using following formula which is not working please help.

```
=IF(A1<>"","",RANDBETWEEN(6,9))
```

Comment: Would a *VBA* solution be acceptable ??

Comment: One obvious flaw in your formula is that you have the true/false logic backwards.  You check the cell above to see if it is not blank.  If it is true that it is not blank, you are in the right place to post a random number, so the `""` and RANDBETWEEN parameters should be reversed, or use `=` instead of `<>`.  However, you don't need the IF test at all because you are putting your formula only in the cells where you need the result.  All you need is the RANDBETWEEN portion.

Comment: Yes @Garry,, no problem with VBA,, ☺

Answer (score 1):

With data like:

[image]

Try this short macro:

```
Sub croupier()
    Dim ary(1 To 4) As Variant
    ary(1) = 6
    ary(2) = 7
    ary(3) = 8
    ary(4) = 9
    Call Shuffle(ary)
    Range("A2") = ary(1)
    Range("A4") = ary(2)
    Range("A6") = ary(3)
    Range("A8") = ary(4)
End Sub

Public Sub Shuffle(InOut() As Variant)
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    Dim tempF As Double, Temp As Variant

    Hi = UBound(InOut)
    Low = LBound(InOut)
    ReDim Helper(Low To Hi) As Double
    Randomize

    For I = Low To Hi
        Helper(I) = Rnd
    Next I


    J = (Hi - Low + 1) \ 2
    Do While J > 0
        For I = Low To Hi - J
          If Helper(I) > Helper(I + J) Then
            tempF = Helper(I)
            Helper(I) = Helper(I + J)
            Helper(I + J) = tempF
            Temp = InOut(I)
            InOut(I) = InOut(I + J)
            InOut(I + J) = Temp
          End If
        Next I
        For I = Hi - J To Low Step -1
          If Helper(I) > Helper(I + J) Then
            tempF = Helper(I)
            Helper(I) = Helper(I + J)
            Helper(I + J) = tempF
            Temp = InOut(I)
            InOut(I) = InOut(I + J)
            InOut(I + J) = Temp
          End If
        Next I
        J = J \ 2
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: @RajeshS .......................... **OK** ...............

Answer (score -1):

Hey friends I've also got a solution. Since using Rand or Randbetween even with Rank is not looking quit useful coz, after any exercise on the worksheet Excel 
re-snuffles the random list.
These two formulas are generating the list I was looking for.

```
B2 = IF(A2<>"",(A2+0),A1+5)

B2 = IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(B2)),0,IF(A2<>"",(A2+0),A1+5))
```

**NB: Original list from A2 to A10.**

Comment: Adding 5 to a number is not exactly "generating a unique random number". Is there a facepalm emoji?

Comment: @Bander,,, it's an intermediate solution,, as I've written also,, Random Numbers reshuffle by Excel after every second execution,, ☺

So to avoid it I created the Solution.

Comment: What's wrong with this answer,,, just write your concern !!